# Microsoft Enterprise Library- ExecuteReader returns closed Datarow

Tags: c#, asp.net, enterprise-library

I am facing  problem with a common function that uses [Execute reader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb748704.aspx) that is part of Microsoft Enterprise Library.

The overall code is as simple as:

```
using (IDataReader dataReader = db.ExecuteReader(sqlCommand))
                {
                    dt.Load(dataReader);
                }
```

The code works perfectly for all scenarios except for one which gives the following outcome:

```
The operation is invalid. OracleDataReader is closed
```

upon checking the property `IsClosed` is also True.

Googling is of no help, Can anyone with prior experience show me a path for the fix.

Comment: Have you verified that there isn't an error in this case that is not being dealt and therefore getting swallowed by the using and that the query in question is actually returning a resultset?

Comment: Ya Query is fine, checked it in SQL Server, Scope of the variables are also fine. The function is called from multiple locations, it is problematic only for one case. I have been checking the SQLCommand for anomalies, assuming that it only could be the source of error, no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Before your `using` statement you should check that the connection is open, if it's not open then you must open it.

```
if (db.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    db.Connection.Open();
}
```

Comment: db doesn't have the property ` Connection.State`, but this is the kind of solution i am looking for. The variable db is of type Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database

Comment: Do you have an OracleConnection object? If so then you should be able to open the connect on that. For reference I'm using the first C# example from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks).